# How to keep linebreaks in Python?

Tags: python, excel, line-breaks

I have an excel sheet which I am reading with Python and uploading to a Help Center.
Some of my excel cells have multiline text, which in my IDE is displayed correctly, but after uploading to my Help Center through an API there are no more line breaks. Everything is now in the same line. 
Is there any way to tell Python to keep all the line breaks as they are in my Excel sheet? 
Anything I can put in my excel file after each line? I tried with \n but that only displays \n in my Help Center lol

This is my code that reads the excel sheet, btw. The text that I want to keep the linebreaks is in the "Body" variable.

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Testmappe.xlsx')

sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sb_list = []

for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):

    sb_dict = {}
    sb = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    sb["Title"] = row_values[2]
    sb["Body"] = row_values[3]
    sb_dict.update(sb)

    sb_list.append(sb_dict)

print(sb_list)

for item in sb_list :
    print(item["Title"])
    print(item["Body"])
```

Comment: Just to source where the problem is - since you mentioned a few elements like the API - where exactly do you notice the problem? You say the multiline text is displayed in your IDE correctly. At what point do you notice the line breaks are lost? For example, when you `print(item["Body"])` is the line break still there? If so, the problem happens later in your code or the API may be stripping tags.

Comment: Yea, when I print(item["Body"]) the line breaks are intact. Only after I upload with the API they are lost. So it sounds like your latter assumption. Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: You'd need to check the API documentation - they may strip tags for their own reasons and you simply cannot get around it. OR they may have a parameter which allows you to pass the `\n` or somehow have a way to indicate new lines. Is the API is for a third party system which you have no control over?

Comment: Yea, unfortunately it is :/

Comment: Assuming they have a support team, I would write to them to ask for support on this, to see if there is any way to achieve line breaks.